# How to draw Predicted Interval Plots (PIPS) using TeeChart

Tags: c#-4.0, teechart

I want to compose a Predicted Interval Plots is it possible to draw the same using Tee Chart

Answer (score 0):

I think is possible. I recommend you taking a look in the, Demo Examples of TeeChartFor.Net, concretely, see the example functions that you find in All Features\Functions.

Could you tell us if the TeeChartFor.Net Demo examples help you  to find as you want?

I hope will helps.

Thanks,

Comment: I have already gone through all the examples that are given in Teechart Demo but none of the gives direction to plot above chart.
Looks like I need to use combination various series to plot the chart

Comment: Hello @Nilesh TeeChart provide you the tools to achieve this type of functions, but it doesn't have a specific function, therefore you must do the calculation. In this point, if you explain exactly what you want, we try to advise you because you can achieve TeeChart works in your end.